# export canvas chart as PDF

Tags: javascript, jquery

using canvas Java script chart , and want to export chart as PDF by using the above URL but it doesn't export chart as PDF. why?
and is there any link to export chart as excel as well?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/canvasjs/cm1qyk2L/ this is the url im using to export chart

Comment: it is exporting pdf. what is your problem?

Comment: Working fine for me as well

Answer (score 1):

You can use FusionCharts js to export canvas chart to PDF or Excel format

For this you need to include below js file

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.fusioncharts.com/code/latest/fusioncharts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.fusioncharts.com/code/latest/themes/fusioncharts.theme.fint.js?cacheBust=56"></script>
```

jsFiddle for the same

http://jsfiddle.net/cm1qyk2L/327/

Comment: @Sidra-zafar Is this helpful to you?

Comment: in which browser...i'm trying in Chorme and working fine